# Regex to Get data from new line after semicolon

Tags: regex, google-apps-script

I am not good at using regex and struggling to make a regex that will get data from new line after the semicolon. For example:

```
Regarding:
267 Covert St Rm 3.5 

Contact Information:
(869) 869-5365 <8698695365>
abc@gmail.com 

Comments:
I'd like to schedule a viewing for Covert St #3.5, Brooklyn, NY 11207, US. 
Please contact me with more information! I am available at 
abc@gmail.com
```

From the above text, I need to get texts under Regarding, contact Information, and comments.

I have made this regex but it is getting whole string:

```
regExp = new RegExp("(?<=Regarding:)(\n).*");
```

I am making a script in Google Apps Script and parsing data from an email.

Comment: Show your desired output.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if is need RegExp in this case. It can be just splitted:

```js
var s = `Regarding:
267 Covert St Rm 3.5 

Contact Information:
(869) 869-5365 <8698695365>
abc@gmail.com 

Comments:
I'd like to schedule a viewing for Covert St #3.5, Brooklyn, NY 11207, US. 
Please contact me with more information! I am available at 
abc@gmail.com`

var regarding = s.split("Regarding:")[1].split("Contact Information:")[0];
console.log(regarding);

var contacts = s.split("Contact Information:")[1].split("Comments:")[0];
console.log(contacts);

var coments = s.split("Comments:")[1];
console.log(coments);
```

If you need just one first line after `:` here you go:

```js
var s = `Regarding:
267 Covert St Rm 3.5 

Contact Information:
(869) 869-5365 <8698695365>
abc@gmail.com 

Comments:
I'd like to schedule a viewing for Covert St #3.5, Brooklyn, NY 11207, US. 
Please contact me with more information! I am available at 
abc@gmail.com`

var regarding = s.split("Regarding:\n")[1].split('\n')[0];
console.log(regarding);

var contacts = s.split("Contact Information:\n")[1].split('\n')[0];
console.log(contacts);

var coments = s.split("Comments:\n")[1].split('\n')[0];
console.log(coments);
```

But your regExp gives about the same result:

```js
var s = `Regarding:
267 Covert St Rm 3.5 

Contact Information:
(869) 869-5365 <8698695365>
abc@gmail.com 

Comments:
I'd like to schedule a viewing for Covert St #3.5, Brooklyn, NY 11207, US. 
Please contact me with more information! I am available at 
abc@gmail.com`

var regExp = new RegExp("(?<=Regarding:)(\n).*");
var r = s.match(regExp)[0];
console.log(r);

var regExp = new RegExp("(?<=Contact Information:)(\n).*");
var c = s.match(regExp)[0];
console.log(c);

var regExp = new RegExp("(?<=Comments:)(\n).*");
var cm = s.match(regExp)[0];
console.log(cm);
```

So, what your problem is, after all?

Comment: not working what? your regex or my split?

Comment: split method is returning whole string.

Comment: What do you mean "whole string"? Did you click on 'Run code snippet'? It returns `267 Covert St Rm 3.5` as a value of `regarding` variable. What a part of the value you need?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, regex **is** the way to go here. This snippet does the job and the `result` array contains all three paragraphs:

```js
const str = 
`Regarding:
267 Covert St Rm 3.5 

Contact Information:
(869) 869-5365 <8698695365>
abc@gmail.com 

Comments:
I'd like to schedule a viewing for Covert St #3.5, Brooklyn, NY 11207, US. 
Please contact me with more information! I am available at 
abc@gmail.com`;

const re = /(?<=:(\n|^)).*?(?=\n\n|$)/gis;

const result = str.match(re);
console.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 2));
```

Comment: Exactly. Probably it makes sense to use more verbose conditions: `/(?<=(Regarding|\nContact Information|\nComments):\n).+?(?=\n(Contact Information|Comments):\n|$)/gs` And it gives the same result as the `split()` method (which was downvoted, by OP I think). I wonder what OP will say? "ti not working at all" or "it's returning whole string"? :)